# Put data from Parquet files into DynamoDB with NiFi

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, apache-nifi, parquet

I want to integrate data into DynamoDB from Parquet files using NiFi (which I run in a Docker container). I fetch my files from AWS S3 using the ListS3 and FetchS3Object processors and then, as I understand it, convert the files to JSON using ConvertRecord and send the data using PutDynamoDB.

I've tried configuring the AvroSchemaRegistry, ParquetReader and JsonRecordSetWriter controllers, but I'm obviously doing it wrong... I've tried using an UpdateAttribute processor too but nothing works. I don't really understand if I have to add the schema and where to add it. Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be an answer directly to your question, as it lacks many details to provide an accurate answer, this is a way that I would simplify your issues:

Use AWS Glue, which can read parquet from S3, using the [S3 connector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-s3-home.html), and write directly to DynamoDB using the [DynamoDB connector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb). There is no need to parse or serialize data, its all handled automatically by Glue.

```py
# Read from S3
dynamicFrame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type = "s3", 
    connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://s3path/"]}, 
    format = "parquet"
)

# Write to DynamoDB
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=dynamicFrame,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.output.tableName": "test_sink",
        "dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "1.0"
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Leeroy. I know that I could use AWS Glue, but I have to use NiFi here. It should be possible with processors but I don't really know which I should use.